# Creating custom taskbar icon in Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, air

I'm trying to create custom icons for my taskbar/desktop icons in my Flex WindowedApplication. So far, I've edited my -app.xml file to include the following:

icons/t_16.png
  icons/t_32.png
  icons/t_48.png
  icons/t_128.png

When the application is run, however, the default flex/air icon is still showing. I have my systemChrome set to standard, and transparent to false, not that they have any relevance to this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually built a release version and installed your air app, or is just the debug version ?

> UPDATE:
>
> You have to deploy a release
> version before the custom application
> icon will be enabled.

Comment: OK. That was it. Edit your answer to read "You have to deploy a release version before the custom application icon will be enabled" and I'll be happy to mark it as the right answer.